# Gitbucket self-Hosting on Nginx MYSQL configuration doesn't work

Tags: mysql, nginx, database, self-hosting

I'm configuring my own self hosted (on Nginx) gitbucket repository and my MYSQL configuration does not work as expected here under **GITBUCKET_HOME/database.conf :**

```
db {
  url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/gitbucket?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8"
  user = "testuser"
  password = "testpassword"
}
```

Do anybody knows what is missing here ? Because i,m **getting Server error 503 Service Unavailable** as soon as i **changed the H2 database to a MYSQL production database** as mentioned here https://github.com/gitbucket/gitbucket/wiki/External-database-configuration:

```
HTTP ERROR 503 Service Unavailable
URI:    /
STATUS: 503
MESSAGE:    Service Unavailable
SERVLET:    -
```

Default H2 database configuration follows also here:

```
db {
  url = "jdbc:h2:${DatabaseHome};MVCC=true"
  user = "sa"
  password = "sa"
}
```

*After researching, i came across this [MS Sql server as external database #1812](https://github.com/gitbucket/gitbucket/issues/1812#issuecomment-354136849) comment, but i'm not sure it's would work !?*

Comment: The default MySQL port is 3306. Have you confirmed MySQL is running on this port and otherwise isn't being blocked (i.e. you can connect to it successfully outside this application)?

Comment: Yes i did all checks before regarding listening port 3306, i don't know, but some others have mentioned in gitbucket issues with MySQL and gitbucket, so i switched also to PostgreSQL als RDMS and ran the proposed PostgreSQL query at the end of configuration as proposed by gitbucket. Every is now up and running.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working (minus MySQL).